# Insert element into array with specific position in loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, array-push

I want to create list of years in array like this:

```
array
(
'2011' => '2011',
'2010' => '2010',
'2009' => '2009',
...
...
'1905' => '1905'
)
```

I try to create this array with loop method like this:

```
$years = array();
for($i=2011;$i>1904;$i--){
  array_push($years,$i);
}
```

But creates an array like this:

```
array
(
'0' => '2011',
'1' => '2010',
'2' => '2009',
...
...
'106' => '1905'
)
```

My question is how can I insert element into array with specific position?
I also look throw relevant question, but couldn't find solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a loop:

```
$years = array_combine(range(2011,1905),range(2011,1905));
```

though I wonder why you need key and value to be identical in your array

Answer (score 3):

```
$years = array();

for($i = 2011; $i > 1904; $i--){
   $years[$i] = $i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$newarray = array();
 for ($i = 2011; $i>1904; $i--)
{
 $newarray[$i]=$i;
}
```